# Gremlin query: How to AND & OR relations?

Tags: graph, nodes, gremlin, traversal, tinkerpop

Say for example I have edges with the types A, B, C or D.

How do I traverse using AND and OR on these edge-types?

Say I want to traverse from node X by ( in(A) AND out(B) ) OR ( both(C) AND out(D) )

The result I expect are all the nodes that have atleast one A-edge that goes to X AND atleast one B-edge that goes from X, OR atleast one C-edge that either goes from or to X AND atleast one D-edge that goes from X.

How do I write a Gremlin query to do this in a general matter? Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
g.V().union(

  // in(A) AND out(B)
  match(
    __.as('1').in('A').as('2'),
    __.as('1').out('B').as('2'))
  .select('2'),

  // OR

  // both(C) AND out(D)
  match(
    __.as('1').both('C').as('2'),
    __.as('1').out('D').as('2'))
  .select('2'))

// Delete duplicates
.dedup()
```

Comment: You should be able to also achieve the same result replacing the `union` step with an `or` step and replacing the `match` steps with simpler `where` steps. I will add another answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you! Always nice to have a different way of doing it. Do you know which solution would perhaps be most efficient, or are they pretty much the same? :)

Comment: It will depend on the backend graph database engine. In general I would always run tests to find out for sure which is better. Some query optimizers may not handle the `match` step as well as some other steps but definitely I would always run tests using representative data to find out. I tend to only use `match` if I can think of no other way in part because I think sometimes the queries become more complex than needed for the reader if not also for the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Using this simple graph

```
g.addV('1').as('1').
  addV('2').as('2').
  addV('3').as('3').
  addV('4').as('4').
  addV('5').as('5').
  addE('B').from('2').to('3').
  addE('A').from('3').to('2')
```

Your initial `match` step

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   match(
......2>     __.as('1').in('A').as('2'),
......3>     __.as('1').out('B').as('2')).
......4>   select('2').by(label)

==>3
```

can be reduced to simply

```
gremlin> g.V().as('1').out('B').filter(out('A').as('1')).label()

==>3
```

Notice only `out` steps are used. The first one takes you to any adjacent vertices. The second, inside the filter, looks to see if there are ways back to where you came from (which from the current vertex point of view is another `out` relationship).

You can use the same pattern to replace the other `match`. The query can be wrapped in an `or` step if you truly want `or` behavior or keep using `union` if you truly want all results that match your constraints.